# How to change a single value in a NumPy array?

Tags: python, numpy

I want to change a single element of an array.
For example, I have:

```
A = np.array([1,2,3,4],
             [5,6,7,8],
             [9,10,11,12],
             [13,14,15,16])
```

I want to relace `A[2][1] = 10` with `A[2][1] = 150`.
How can I do it?

Comment: The [reason](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.indexing.html#single-element-indexing) this method isn't working is because what you are technically doing is first returning a new array `A[2]`, and then subsequently accessing element `[1]` of this array.  Always use @Allen's method for assigning a value.

Comment: See [the documentation on indexing in NumPy](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/arrays.indexing.html).

Answer (score 83, accepted):

Is this what you are after? Just index the element and assign a new value.

```
A[2,1]=150

A
Out[345]: 
array([[ 1,  2,  3,  4],
       [ 5,  6,  7,  8],
       [ 9, 150, 11, 12],
       [13, 14, 15, 16]])
```

Comment: Is there a reason that Numpy arrays are referred to with `[x,y]` rather than `[x][y]`? Is it just to differentiate them from regular Python arrays?

Comment: @JammyDodger A bit late, but numpy "arrays" are represented as a contiguous 1D vector in memory while python "arrays" are just lists. A multidimensional vector in numpy is contiguous while python treats them as a list of lists. Their implementations are different. Python multidimensional lists have no information on their inner lists, thus you must use [x][y].

Comment: Confusion may be avoided if this is referred to as `[y, x]`.  Numpy defines array coordinates using C-order indexing, so for 2D data stored in standard raster order, the y coordinate comes first.